# python: in __getattr__ raise AttributeError, attr AttributeError: __len__

Tags: python-2.7

```
def get_site(r):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
```

This is the code I am using. The r mentioned is the url which is requested from another function.

```
r=urllib2.request(url)
```

The error which shows while running the python code is this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 229, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: __len__ `
```

Can you please help me fix it? The url is https format and I am using python 2.7

Update: the whole code is here:

`def web(url,a):
    def get_url(url):
        import urllib2
        base=url
        r=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        return r
    def get_site(r):
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        for lt in soup.find_all("a",class_="url"):
            if lt.get("href"):
                si=lt.get("href")
        name=soup.find_all("h4",itemprop="name")
        cat="username-%s, site-%s\n"%(name,si)
        with open("/home/agneljeo/Desktop/url.txt","w") as ul1:
            ul1.write(cat)
            ul1.close()
            return soup
    def get_fol(soup):
        global url1
        url1=""
        for item in soup.find_all("a",class_="d-inline-block no-underline mb-1"):
            if len(item.get("href"))<2:
                url1=item.get("href")
                break
        return url1
    def main():
        gu=get_url(url)
        gs=get_site(gu)
        gf=get_fol(gs)
        if a>0:
            web(gf,a-1)
    main()`

The url is called at the terminal explicitly and the url is mentioned in the comments bellow

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead of request

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url='https://github.com/johnpapa?tab=followers'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for lt in soup.find_all("a",class_="url"):
    if lt.get("href"):
        si=lt.get("href")
        print si
```

> `xxx@xxxx-xxxx:~/Desktop$ python sa.py 
>   http://johnpapa.net`

here is how you can goto follower page and grab his followers
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib2
url='https://github.com/johnpapa?tab=followers'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for lt in soup.find_all("a",class_="url"):
    if lt.get("href"):
        si=lt.get("href")
        print si
for item in soup.find_all("a",class_="d-inline-block no-underline mb-1"):
        url1=item.get("href")
        url1='https://github.com'+url1+'?tab=followers'
        print url1
        content = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        for lt in soup1.find_all("a",class_="url"):
            if lt.get("href"):
                si=lt.get("href")
                print si
        for item in soup1.find_all("a",class_="d-inline-block no-underline mb-1"):
                url1=item.get("href")
                url1='https://github.com'+url1+'?tab=followers'
                print url1
```

output:

> `xxxx@xxxx-xxxx:~/Desktop$ python sa.py
>   http://johnpapa.net
>   https://github.com/gu1ma?tab=followers
>   ...`

Comment: the code after `soup=BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')` is `for lt in soup.find_all("a",class_="url"):` so for that urlopen(url).read is necessary or .request...?

Comment: urllib2.urlopen(url).read() will gets complete source of the page

Comment: btw the new error is `ValueError: unknown url type: ` even though the url form is of https: and url taken is (https://github.com/johnpapa?tab=followers)

Comment: can see the complete code so that it helps me solve because i tried the same url and it worked

Comment: it works only just as the same output which came for you...but how to make it work for different urls called explicitily in`get_fol` function i need to run it in a loop until i get thier sites from 20 random followers...please check the main function

Comment: why are you using if len(item.get("href"))<2:

Comment: since from url1 you get only relative paths as /user you can't directly pass the path to urllib2 so you need make it absolute like url='https://github.com'+url1+'?tab=followers' which will go to followers page